# "O/U Hitze" in German Recipes

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviation

What does O/U stand for in German recipes? For example:

> Backofen auf 175 Grad O/U Hitze vorheizen

which roughly means "preheat the oven to 175 C". I don't understand what O/U adds to the sentence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here, *O/U Hitze* is short for *Ober-/Unterhitze*, "top/bottom heat", referring to a setting of the oven to heat with both top and bottom heat.

However, this abbreviation and this form of writing does not seem standard to me. I guess, it would rather be *O-/U-Hitze* instead.

Comment: [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/backofen+ober+unterhitze.html) gives some examples. For those of us with less fancy ovens, apparently "top heat" is called the "broil" setting, "bottom heat" is the "bake" setting, and a combination of the two is top/bottom heat.

Comment: [Here's the corresponding icon you'll find on the oven](https://www.backofenratgeber.de/wp-content/uploads/backofen-symbole.gif)

Answer (score 4):

The shorthand refers to *Ober-/Unterhitze*, an oven setting where heat comes both from above and below. In English, this would be top/bottom heat and on most ovens this is represented by a pictogram of a rectangle with thick bars below the top and above the bottom line.

It adds information to the sentence as many German ovens also have an *Umluft* setting; the corresponding pictogram shows a fan in the middle of the rectangle. In English, this would be a fan oven or circulating air. (Furthermore, the separate *Oberhitze* and *Unterhitze* settings exist but I personally have not found them required in any recipe so far.)

If your oven does both you might be inclined to replace *Ober-/Unterhitze* with *Umluft* and reduce the temperature by 10–20 °C. However note that this is not an option for all recipes.